# Which of the following procedures will allow the student to determine the rate constant, for the reaction?

Tags: kinetics

[image]

Is the answer A or B because C and D won't give me the rate constant?

Comment: C or D won't give you the rate constant.

Comment: C will only let you identify the order of reaction of X in this reaction and D will change the rate constant as the temperature change

Comment: Tty to develop an straight equation equation from the rate equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the graph it is clear that the reaction follows first order kinetics ($\ce{[X] = [X_0] e^{-kt}}$) where $ [X_0]$ is initial concentration. Taking $ln$ on both sides we get 
$\ce{ln[X] = ln[X_0] +(-kt)}$ 
So if you plot a graph between $ln[X]$ and $t$ then you have the magnitude of slope as k ie the equilibrium constant. 
So correct answer is A.